# How to use | pipe operator in query params in spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, query-string

I want to use | pipe operator in my query params value but when I do so it gives me 400 BAD REQUEST. How should I pass | in my query param value.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the pipe ( | ) symbol in your uri.
If you replace the symbol with %7C it will be a valid uri.

Spring will translate %7C to |

More info about encoding: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp